# Match all unicode characters that are also present in windows-1251 table

Tags: php, regex

Is there a way to match all UTF-8 chars that have their windows-1251 counterparts without manually matching the number of each one? There are certain ranges, but there are too many out-of-range characters. I'd like to save some time if possible.

Comment: Had you hit a practical performance issue with this and if so could you show how you currently perform the check? win-1251 is what, 256 characters total? That doesn't seem like a huge set to compare against.

Comment: I currently don't. I'm building a list of characters, but it's very annoying. I thought there MIGHT be an easier way, so I asked. Besides, it could be a much longer list than that, so it would definitely be useful info.

Comment: I don't think there is any convenient _algorithm_ for such check, at least I can't think of one.

Comment: Well, I found a way, as you can see. And there were no reasons to downvote, it can be very important for people in a similar situation. There's no need to build a list of all the characters, just checking if it converts to the respective charset is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a smart way to solve this, even though I already almost finished the list of chars. I'll post it in the context of my project, but it can be adjusted to other situations easily.

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '#[^.]#u', function($matches) {
        if ( null == (iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251//IGNORE", $matches[0])) ) {
            return 'replace_pattern';
        }
        else return $matches[0];
    },
    $text
);
```

Basically, with `iconv` I check if the unicode symbol can be converted to windows-1251, and if it can, then I return the same symbol, but if can't (`//IGNORE` returns `null` in such cases), I return my replacement pattern. I'm pretty sure it will come useful to whoever is in a similar situation.

Comment: Note that iconv (1) can emit a notice if it doesn't like input to convert and (2) might output a broken character instead of false in some cases. Try running this on euro symbol for example `€`.

Comment: Euro symbol is present in cp-1251 table. I tested my script against the whole cp-1251 table. It works flawlessly.

Comment: Ah, my mistake then, probably messed output looking at output. :)